# Use other than index.html for Github pages

Tags: github, hosting, github-pages

I have recently started using github pages and so far I am using the default index.html as my main page.  How do I use another page as my default page? For example if in my gh-pages branch I have my html in a folder src/. How do I set ./src/index.html as my default instead of ./index.html?

Comment: Did you try a symlink?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create dummy index.html and put this in the header

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://mysite.github.io/folder/index.html" />
```

Change http://mysite.github.io/folder/index.html to your desired url.

Comment: Wouldn't this take more time to load the homepage? (because of redirecting)

Answer (score 0):

I though [Steven Penny's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330188/use-other-than-index-html-for-github-pages#comment43126572_27330188) was good, but on Windows it was not super straightforward to create a symlink inside git. Only more recent versions of git-for-windows [support symlinks](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/Symbolic-Links).

If you enable support via the `core.symlinks` config variable you can `mklink index.html src\file.html` and gh-pages will show file.html as the landing page.