# How do I make Sphinx documentation play nicely with GitHub pages?

Tags: github, github-pages, python-sphinx

I am trying to elegantly setup my Sphinx to work with GitHub pages. I want to maintain separate `build` and `source` directories (seen in the directory tree below).

```
repository
├── docs
│   ├── build
│   │   └── index.html
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── source
|       | ...
|
├── README.md
└── src
    | ...
```

I have the GitHub repository set to look for the `index.html` in `/docs/`.

**Question:** Is there a way to place a *symbolic link* or an `index.html` in the root of /docs/ that points to `/docs/build/index.html`?

Comment: I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330188/use-other-than-index-html-for-github-pages#comment43126572_27330188) which allows you to set the absolute url path to my desired `/docs/build/index.html` with the use of a dummy. It works, but it's perhaps not as elegant as I would have liked. Is there another way?

Comment: Since you just upload the built docs yourself it's not that related, but if you ever plan to run sphinx in the github-actions CI, this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57989790/using-github-actions-to-publish-documentation

Comment: Thanks, that's appreciated. I'll be looking into that.